# Storing user login data in Business logic layer during session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core

I've got project with dll dependecies like below:
DataAccessLayer(DAL) <- BusinessLogicLayer(BLL) <- MVC Web App(WEB)

The project needs to connect with database by separated SQL logins (Each SQL login means different App user or in other words already existing database users and passwords will be used as app users/logins). So thre's no way to youse default connection.

I'm passing class "Connection" (Class is defined on BLL so DAL can see it but WEB can't) to my Context class to make connection with database like below:

```
public class WMSContext : DbContext
{
    public WMSContext(Connection con)
        : base(con.ContextOption)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UsersConfig> UsersConfig { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UsersGroup> UsersGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UsersGroupConfig> UsersGroupConfig { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ShipmentVehicles> ShipmentVehicles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<VSHIPMENTS> VSHIPMENTS { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<VShipmentsDetails> VShipmentsDetails { get; set; }
}



public class Connection
{
    public string Login { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public string Server { get; private set; }
    public string Database { get; private set; }
    public DbContextOptions<WMSContext> ContextOption { get; private set; }

    public Connection(string servAddr, string dbName, string login, string pass)
    {

        Login = login;
        Password = pass;
        Server = servAddr;
        Database = dbName;
        string connStr = "Data Source = " + servAddr + "; Initial Catalog = "+ dbName + "; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = "+ login + "; Password = "+ pass+ "";
        var optBuild = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WMSContext>();
        optBuild.UseSqlServer(connStr);
        ContextOption = optBuild.Options;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the instance of Connection class should be stored somwhere during user session to perform other requests for certain SQL user. My first thought was to assign instance of Connection to Session. Something like below:

Connection = new Connection(){ some login data }
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Login Data", connection);

but in that case i would have to set DAL dependent to WEB and it not seems to be elegant slolution. Sure i can just extract that Connection class to class liblary that will be shared by all projects but i'm curious if there is some way to store data only in BLL and only temporary and delete them when WEB user session ends?
Or maybe there is some other way than using Sessions?

Comment: for something like this, maybe you could use a factory or similar to new up repositories which pass in the connection string? this way the only direct dependency is a simple string which you pass on to the data access layer and it handles getting the right repo for the user?

Comment: An application essentially needs only one connection to a database, with credentials for that application. Your users aren't connecting to the DB, your app is. User authentication and authorization is something your app needs to take care of, not the database.

Comment: is it really one connection string per user, or is it something different like one database per tenant and each tenant has a user pool? if so there might be better solutions like resolving the correct connection based on tenant identifier?

Comment: It is must  be just as i described each user must have own connection string. Web site is basically user interface for already existing Database -
 side solution and there is no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create a context object with an interface that you can inject into the DAL. That way the DAL will depend on your interface but not on any web-specific APIs.

For example

```
interface IDatabaseAuthenticationContext
{
    string DatabaseUserName { get; set; }
    string DatabasePassword { get; set ; }
}

class AuthenticationContext: IDatabaseAuthenticationContext
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public AuthenticationContext(HttpContextbase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public string DatabaseUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _httpContext.Session["DatabaseUserName"];
        }
        set
        {
            _httpContext.Session["DatabaseUserName"] = value;
        }
    }
    public string DatabasePassword
    {
        get
        {
            return _httpContext.Session["DatabasePassword"];
        }
        set
        {
            _httpContext.Session["DatabasePassword"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your DAL:

```
class DataAccessLayer : IDataAccessLayer
{
    private readonly IDatabaseAuthenticationContext _dbAuthenticationContext;

    public DataAccessLayer(IDatabaseAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        _dbAuthenticationContext = context; //Injected
    }

    public void ExecuteSomeCommand()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(this.CreateConnectionString()))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SomeCommand");
            cmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    private string CreateConnectionString()
    {
        return String.Format("Server={0};UID={1};PWD={2}", this.GetServerName(),
                                                           _dbAuthenticationContext.DatabaseUserName,
                                                           _dbAuthenticationContext.Databasepassword);
    }
```

Then in your composition root:

```
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseAuthenticationContext, AuthenticationContext>();
container.RegisterType<HttpContextBase, () => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
container.RegisterType<IDataAccessLayer, DataAccessLayer>();
```

This way you can pass what you need to the DAL without requiring the DAL to know anything about `HttpContext` or other web-specific APIs. If you ever write a console application (or other program without a reference to System.Web), you just need to write a different implementation of `AuthenticationContext` that implements `IDatabaseAuthenticationContext`.